# How to open a URL through a Rest request call

Tags: c#, .net, rest

I have a very generic question.
I have a desktop browser from which I click a URL.

This URL belongs to my restful service /Get verb.

I would like the controller action to open a website and also initiate a http 200 back to the browser.

In .net core, is this achievable? Like opening a URL from a controller action?

Comment: It's not very clear, what do you mean under 'open a website'? And for returning http 200 back to the browser - there is type IActionResult in c#, which allows you to return 200 OK status code via `return Ok()`

Comment: I think you'll have to try it out and show us your attempt in code. What you're describing sounds to me very much like the basics for how a web application works - so it should definitely be possible.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that by using Redirect() function derived from the Controller base allows us to open a url.

The Redirect needs to be passed the url as an arg.